# Error in DevIL. cannot open file 'il_wrap.lib'

Tags: visual-c++, dev-c++, devil

I am using DevIL in my vc++ application. When build the application I get an error fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'il_wrap.lib'. There is no such file (il_wrap.lib). I am using DevIL-SDK-x86-1.7.8. From where did I get the file il_wrap.lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in the folder where you installed/downloaded/copied the DevIL library. Check that you use correct 32-bit/64-bit, static/dynamic linkable .LIB file.

Comment: I am using 32bit. There is no such file in the downloaded item.

Comment: Probably you need to build the DevIL on your system to build up files/directories on your system. Then you may find the said file.

Comment: The downloaded SDK contains only some header files and library files. I am using tese files in my application. When I am trying to build the application I get the error. Can I download the il_wrap.lib. Is it available? Thanks for your answer and comment, ajay